# Using Laravel Eloquent to count how many times something exists in an efficient manner

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table called rentals, within each row are columns state,city,zipcode which all house ids to another table with that info. There are about 3400 rentals. I am pulling each column to display the states,city and zipcode distinctly. I need to show how many rentals are in each one. I am doing this now via ajax, the person starts typing in what they want to see and it auto completes it with the count, but its slow because of the way im doing it.

```
$rentals_count = Rentals::where('published',1)->get();
foreach($states as $state) {
    echo $state.”-“.$rentals_count->where(‘state’,$state->id)->count();
}
```

Above is roughly what im doing with pieces removed because they are not related to this question. Is there a better way to do this? It lags a bit so the auto complete seems broken to a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Eager loading your eloquent query? Eager loading is used to reduce query operations. When querying, you may specify which relationships should be eager loaded using the `with` method:

```
$rental_counts = Rentals::where('published',1)->with('your_relation')->get();
```

You can read more about that in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$rentals = Rentals::wherePublished(true)->withCount('state')->get();
```

When you loop through `$rentals`, the result will be in `$rental->state_count`

Answer (score 0):

Setup a relation 'state' on rentals then call it like this

```
$rentals_count = Rentals::where('published',1)->with('state')->get()->groupBy('state');

$rentals_count->map(function($v, $k){
          echo $v[0]->state->name .' - '. $v->count();
     });
```

Meanwhile in Rentals Model

```
public function state(){
    return $this->hasOne(State::class, 'state'); //state being your foreign key on rentals table. The primary key has to be id on your states table
}
```